# Largest ideal contained in the intersection of two ideals?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Suppose $I,J$ are ideals of a ring $R$. I know that $I+J$ is the smallest ideal containing $I\cup J$. Is $IJ$ the largest ideal contained in $I\cap J$?

For example, $2\Bbb Z$ and $3\Bbb Z$ are ideals of $\Bbb Z$. Their intersection $6\Bbb Z$ is itself an ideal of $\Bbb Z$. Their product $2\Bbb Z$$3\Bbb Z=6\Bbb Z$, which makes it the largest ideal contained in their intersection.

Is this true in general?

Comment: Don't delete your question just after getting your answer. This is unkind to those who took time to answer your question, and unkind to others who would have the same question in the future. It also makes it appear as though you are trying to hide something.

Comment: It's important to note that $I \cap J$ is an ideal, and certainly contained in itself. Hurkyl provides good insight in the case $R=\mathbb{Z}$ in his answer. Another thought: being contained in $I \cap J$ does not mean properly contained.

Comment: @mixedmath Perhaps you could list me the circumstances when I am at liberty to use the 'delete' button?

Comment: @HritRoy Deletion is most often used when someone mistypes a question (or otherwise gives a meaningless question and recognizes it), or gives an incorrect answer. If you are looking for a barometer to determine whether it's a bad idea, you should think: am I deleting other's good efforts? If so, then you shouldn't delete. If you are only deleting your own mistakes, then it might be a reasonable delete.

Answer (score 1):

$I \cap J$ is the largest ideal contained in $I \cap J$.

In some situations $IJ = I \cap J$, but this definitely isn't always true. As a counterexample in the integers, take $I=J=2 \mathbb{Z}$. Then $I \cap J = 2 \mathbb{Z}$ but $IJ = 4 \mathbb{Z}$.

In the integers, the generator of $I \cap J$ is a *least common multiple* of the generators of $I$ and $J$, so you will have $I \cap J = IJ$ when $I$ and $J$ are relatively prime (i.e. $I+J=1$).